# Refresh a screen after state change [Drawer navigator react-native]

Tags: ios, react-native, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I have a DrawerNavigator in StackNavigator. I have implemented the structure to achieve Hamburger menu function. I have a listing home page with a hamburger menu icon. On clicking the icon, I open a menu just like how it is in Amazon, flipkart apps. The menu list is dynamic, I need to refresh the list on state change.

Here is my view hierarchy:

```
export const DrawerMenu = DrawerNavigator({
    Search: {
        screen: Search,
    },
    SidebarMenuComponent: {
        screen: SidebarMenuComponent,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: Logo,
        }
    },
  }, {
    contentComponent: SidebarMenuComponent,
    drawerWidth: 250,
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  });

const RootStack = StackNavigator({ 

    Search: {
        screen: DrawerMenu,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: Logo,
        }
    },

    ThankYou: {
        screen: ThankYou,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'ThankYou',
            gesturesEnabled: false,
        }
    },
  });
```

I am not able to reload it. So my question here is, how can we force to reload the list for this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) triggering render() to re-rendering, so the display will change immediately

*__"You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering"__*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

I fixed the issue by importing `SidebarMenuContainer` and assigned it to contentComponent 
instead of `SidebarMenuComponent`.

Comment: Its little bit late but can explain with code how you did this ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add `addListener` to navigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

I was using react-navigation v5 and unmountOnBlur option worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/62675176/5970652