# Unmount or re-render screen in drawer navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just added drawer navigator recently and wrapped my screens in `createDrawerNavigator()`

These are my current routes:

- Home.js
- Post.js
- Settings.js

When a user navigates from **Home** to **Post** I pass a param that has the post data.

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Post', {postData: postData})}
```

When ever the user goes back to **Home** from **Post**, then post will be unmounted. and mounted back again with fresh data when another post is clicked.

My issue is that with implementing the drawer, the **Post** screen does not get unmounted when navigating back to **home**, I keep gettings the same props and screen of the first post opened, over and over again.

This is my route setup:

```js
import React from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Post from './screens/Post';
import Settings from './screens/Settings';
import SideBar from './screens/sidebar';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Post: {screen: Post},
    Settings: {screen: Settings}
},
{
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    backBehavior: 'initialRoute',
    contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
}
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
    Drawer: {screen: Drawer},
    },
    {
    initialRouteName: "Drawer",
        headerMode: "none",
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want each post screen to open and re render as new when navigating to it from Home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use to face the same issue. I made my screen `Post` listen to navigation focus event triggered by `react-nativation` [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) instead of `componentDidMount`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

const Post = () => (
  <View>
    <NavigationEvents
      onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus',payload)}
      onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus',payload)} // 
      onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur',payload)}
      onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur',payload)}
    />
    {/* 
      Your view code
    */}
  </View>
);
```

With `onDidFocus`, you may get the navigation param, fetch data, and/or update state. You may clear screen state with `onDidBlur` if needed.

Alternatively, you can do imperative coding as [this doc here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

## Update :

By the way, I am wondering why you put `Post` with Drawer? Is it just to have a link in the drawer that can access to the Post page?

In my opinion, you should move `Home` and `Post` to new stack and make `Home` as initial Route. This will make sure that the Post is unmounted after navigating back to `Home`.

Check out my sample below

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigatior({
   Home: {screen: Home},
   Post: {screen: Post},
}, {
   initialRouteName: 'Home', 
   ...
})

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    HomeStack
    Settings: {screen: Settings}
},
{
    initialRouteName: "HomeStack",
    backBehavior: 'initialRoute',
    contentOptions: {
       activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
}
);
```

Comment: check my posted answer I think I fixed it, not sure why!

Comment: Screens in `createDrawerNavigator` mounted once in the similar way like Tab. But for Stack, navigating back will remove (unmount) the top screen

Comment: Yes that's what I did, what I was doing wrong is flipping `createDrawerNavigator` with `createStackNavigator`, thank you for clarifying how they work.

Comment: works, also I had to move the api call I had in my init `useEffect` to the `onDidFocus` in order to prevent double api call.

Comment: @panchicore: at that time, hook not yet exists :D

Answer (score 36):

For those using react-navigation v5. I faced the same issue my component was not unmounting by using `goBack()` for a screen link in drawer. After little research I found our that in latest version of react-navigation they have added an attribute `unmountonblur` in screen options for drawer navigator by default its false that's why component doesn't unmount. I am using this to solve my problem.

Here is my code

```
<Drawer.Screen name="ResetLogsStack" component={ResetLogsStack} options={{unmountOnBlur:true}}/>
```

Here is the link for that: [unmountonblur](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#unmountonblur)

Comment: wow.. you save my day.. this is perfect answer for those using the v5. Thank you..

Comment: Worked like a charm for me... Thanks Mate 

Comment: For direct link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#unmountonblur

Comment: Working perfectly!!! Thanks...

Comment: you rock, this worked great

Answer (score 3):

It's the way `react-navigation` works, to counter this you can add listeners, like so:

```
<NavigationEvents
    onDidFocus={payload => { console.log(payload.state.params,'<- this has your new params') }}
/>
```

**OR**

```
 this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload=>{console.log(payload)})
```

Check [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) for more information

Answer (score 2):

I lost several hours on this after updating React Navigation from 2.14.2 to 3.11.0. The funny thing is that it was working perfectly and after upgrade pages were not re-rendering which was causing to wrong language and not actual data on the pages. 
What I have found is the issue [DrawerNavigator screen shouldn't unmount](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2277)

So part of us complain why it is not rerendering screens and part was complaining why it was rerendering. The second part won the battle :)

Basically the solution was as expected: to listen to WillFocus event...
Just add this to code to your component if you want it to be rerendered on each visit.

```
 /**
 * When using React Navigation Component is not umnounted and instead stored in navigator. 
 * We need component to be rerendered during each visit to show right info and language
 */
componentDidMount() {
    //this.props.navigation will come in every component which is in navigator
    focusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
        'willFocus',
        payload => {
            this.forceUpdate();//Native react function to force rerendering
        }
    );
    this.setState({focusSubscription: focusSubscription});
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.focusSubscription.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the method suggested in the answers but they didn't work perfectly with my case.

**Solution:**

I tried to flip `createDrawerNavigator()` with `createStackNavigator()` and it worked perfectly like before!
I don't have to use react navigation events, normal event like `componentWillUnmount` and `componentWillMount` work perfectly.

```js
const MainScreens = createStackNavigator(
{
   Home: {screen: Home},
   Post: {screen: Post},
   Settings: {screen: Settings}
},
{
   initialRouteName: "Home",
   headerMode: "none",
}
);

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
{
   Main: {screen: MainScreens},
},
{
   initialRouteName: "Main",
   backBehavior: 'initialRoute',
   contentOptions: {
   activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
   },
   contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
}
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Not sure if there's anything wrong in what I did, but its working fine until now.

Answer (score 1):

As per Muhammad Zain response, if you are using react navigation v5, you can pass directly to the Drawer screen the option unmountOnBlur

> options={{unmountOnBlur:true}}

and that will be enough.

[React navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#unmountonblur)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-navigation for months. But placing screens directly into Drawer navigator prevents willunmount method to be called. First place screen in a stack navigator then place it into drawer navigator.